# How to get list of all combinations of pairs of character strings in R

Tags: r

I have multiple character strings, let's say 'pred_1', 'pred_2' and 'pred_3'. Now I want to get a list with all pairs of the strings. So, the resulting list should contain 'pred_1 pred_2', 'pred_1 pred_3' and 'pred_2 pred_3'. Does anyone know how to automate this for more than three character strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is `combn`

```
combn(v1, 2, simplify = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- paste0("pred_", 1:3)
```